# How to change scrollbar step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

When I click on button up/down I need step 24px.

**How I can do thet**

``` scrollbar ``scrollTop=24px ```

Comment: Are you talking about the built in scrollbar of the browser? Doubt you can do that without manually going into a user'c browser config and finding some setting that controls it (if there is even one).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
function scrollWin() {

    // Scroll (horizontally, vertically) by pixels
    window.scrollBy(0, 24);
}
```

Now you can attach this to a KeyPressed Event or anything else you want:

```
// register event
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

//function to be fired on keydown (keypressed won't work in this situation)
function checkKey(e) {

Set your event variable if not already set.
    e = e || window.event;

    // Arrow Up.
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {

        // minus because we want to go up
        window.scrollBy(0, -24);
    }
    // Arrow down
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {

       // plus we want to go down.
       window.scrollBy(0, 24);
    }
}
```

Here are all Key Arrow Codes:

- left = 37
- up = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40

Regards, Megajin